# How do I create a mutation schema on a nested object with GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to create a graphql mutation to update an object field with an array of other objects. Here is my schema:

```
"url":
  post:
      summary: Saves user properties
      operationId: saveProperties
      consumes:
      - application/json
      produces:
      - application/json
      parameters:
      - in: body
        name: request
        description: request
        required: true
        schema:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/SavePropertiesDto"
          originalRef: SavePropertiesDto
  SavePropertiesDto:
    type: object
    required:
    - saveProperties
    properties:
      saveProperties:
        type: array
        items:
          "$ref": "#/definitions/SavePropertyDto"
          originalRef: SavePropertyDto
  SavePropertyDto:
    type: object
    required:
    - agree
    - Id
    properties:
      agree:
        type: boolean
      Id:
        type: string
    title: SavePropertyDto
```

I wanna to query saveProperties and my query looks like this:

```
     mutation someFunc($requestBody: [SavePropertyInput!]) {
          saveProperties(requestBody: $requestBody) {
            agree
            Id
          }
```

I'm getting errors

```
Field \"saveProperties\" must not have a selection since type \"JSON\" has no subfields
```

when I execute this request. Also I don't wait for response to this query and wait for only 204 code. As i understood I need to pass SavePropertyInput as a variable to query request. Sorry for visuality, I used yml format for data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: error is related to [bad] return type (not args) ... mutation probably returns some [unknown sturcture/type - fallback?] JSON scalar